# Argument Error Chosen-Rails CSS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to implement the [chosen-rails](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails) gem. It's worked for me in the past. But this time I'm getting the following error:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
  (in /home/user/.rbenv/versions/2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/chosen-rails-1.1.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/chosen.css.scss)
```

The chosen.css.scss can be found [here](https://github.com/tsechingho/chosen-rails/blob/v1.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets/chosen.css.scss). And the issue seems to be caused by the first three lines:

```
@import "compass/css3/box-sizing";
@import "compass/css3/images";
@import "compass/css3/user-interface";
```

Any of them alone is sufficient to cause the Argument Error. And when they are removed (and when I also remove the relevant variable names from the css) the error stops and the page renders--albeit in an ugly fashion. So the root of the issue is unknown. I don't see any arguments being passed in! Any help would be appreciated.

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
 *= require chosen
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require chosen-jquery
//= require scaffold
//= require_tree .

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({
        allow_single_deselect: true,
        no_results_text: 'No results matched',
        width: '400px'
    });
});
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'chosen-rails', '1.1.0'
```

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

Answer (score 0):

A similar scss error was described [here](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/253#issuecomment-59492237) albeit not for the chosen-rails gem. There the issue seemed to be an outdated version of sass. Apparently there's an issue with the sass gem v 3.2.0 that's fixed by v 3.2.19. Looked in my Gemfile.lock and lo! I had sass 3.2.0. So I explicitly specified the newer version in my Gemfile and ran `bundle update sass`. Restarted the server, and boom. It worked!